How to use Elixir SFTPClient to authenticate with private key
I want to authenticate via SSH into a machine that requires a private key. The key of the target machine is in the directory "~/.ssh/id_rsa_nop". When I authenticate using a different library ( librarian ) the authentication works. This code with Librarian works:
   {:ok, conn} = SSH.connect(
      "whatever.com",  
      user: "root",
      identity: "~/.ssh/id_rsa_nop",
      save_accepted_host: false,
      silently_accept_hosts: true,
      user_interaction: false
    )

When I try to authenticate with SFTPClient, I get an error message:
[error] GenServer #PID<0.1217.0> terminating
** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol String.Chars not implemented for %SFTPClient.ConnError{message: "server failed to start sftp subsystem"} of type SFTPClient.ConnError (a struct). This protocol is implemented for the following type(s): Atom, BitString, Date, DateTime, Decimal, Float, Hex.Solver.Assignment, Hex.Solver.Constraints.Empty, Hex.Solver.Constraints.Range, Hex.Solver.Constraints.Union, Hex.Solver.Incompatibility, Hex.Solver.PackageRange, Hex.Solver.Term, Integer, List, NaiveDateTime, Phoenix.LiveComponent.CID, Postgrex.Copy, Postgrex.Query, Time, URI, Version, Version.Requirement

The syntax I use is here:
   config = [
      host: "whatever.com",
      port: 22,
      user: "root",
      private_key_path: "~/.ssh/id_rsa_nop",
    ]


    case  SFTPClient.connect(config) do
      {:ok, conn} ->
        IO.puts("Successfully connected!")
        # You can now use `conn` to interact with the SFTP server
       IO.inspect conn

      {:error, reason} ->
        IO.puts("Failed to connect: #{reason}")
    end
    {:noreply, assign(socket, ssh_conn: "")}

How do I perform the same action with SFTPClient?
I tried using this as well:
:user_dir - The directory to read private keys from.

Documentation is here: https://hexdocs.pm/sftp_client/SFTPClient.Operations.Connect.html#connect/1
Thank you.

Maybe adding inspect() to your error would help see a bit more about why the connection is failing: IO.puts("Failed to connect: #{inspect(reason)}")?
Can you try initiating SFTP connections to other servers?  I.e. is the problem with the SFTP subsystem independent of any particular server?  Maybe try using a fully-qualified path to your key?  Just a few ideas.
